# entity framework migration seed method duplicating records

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Data model: Song - Artists (N:N)

I'm trying to seed my database, but for some reason my Artists are getting duplicate after the seed method has ran. I'm not sure why...

```
    CreateSong("COLDPLAY", "Viva la vida", context);
    CreateSong("COLDPLAY", "UP & UP", context);
    CreateSong("COLDPLAY", "UP & UP", context);
```

CreateSong method:

```
    public Song CreateSong(String artistName, String title, NeosicDbContext context)
    {
        var ret = context.Songs.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Title == title && s.Artists.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == artistName) != null);
        if(ret != null)
        {
            return ret;
        }

        **var artists = new List<Artist>();
        var artist = context.Artists.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == artistName);
        if (artist == null)
        {
            artist = new Artist { Name = artistName };
            context.Artists.Add(artist);
        }
        artists.Add(artist);**
        var tags = new List<Tag>();
        tags.Add(defaultTag);

        ret = new Song {
            Title = title,
            Artists = artists,
            Tags =  tags
        };
        context.Songs.Add(ret);
        //context.MarkAsModified(ret);
        return ret;
    }
```

Db result: 
3 artists, while I'm only expecting one.
[image]

Tried both with `context.Artists.Add(artist);` and without but results remains the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem comes here:

```
var artist = context.Artists.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == artistName);
```

this query systematically  hits the db. But, before `SaveChanges`, the db is empty.

So, you should do something like:

```
//check the context (I would like to say the *cache*, but it is a false friend in this case)
var artist = context.Artists.Local.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == artistName);
if ( artist == null) {
    //then hit the db
    artist = context.Artists.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == artistName);
}
```

Comment: did not know there was "Local" property. Thanks! Works like a charm now.